# VB ComboBoxes (SelectedValue and Filter)

Tags: combobox

Looking to

> Filter a ComboBox based on the value selected from another ComboBox

Having trouble getting the `SelectedValue` to become the `Filter parameter`.  Hope that makes sense.

```
        stringValue = cobContractNetworkGroup.SelectedValue

    If stringValue = "Something" Then

        cobAffiliation.Enabled = True

        AppReturnAffiliationBindingSource.Filter = "AffiliationType LIKE '%" & AppReturnGroupContractNetworkBindingSource.Current & "%' "

    Else
        cobAffiliation.Enabled = False
        AppReturnAffiliationBindingSource.Filter = ""

    End If
```